# Linear probing in Hashing implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

I am trying to solve this problem where I need to implement Linear Probing.

Given an array of integers and a hash table size. Fill the array elements into a hash table using Linear Probing to handle collisions.

Example 1:

```
Input:
hashSize = 10
sizeOfArray = 4
Array[] = {4,14,24,44}

Output:
-1 -1 -1 -1 4 14 24 44 -1 -1
```

Example 2:

```
Input:
hashSize = 10
sizeOfArray = 4
Array[] = {9,99,999,9999}

Output:
99 999 9999 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 9
```

Your Task:
You don't need to read input or print anything.

Your task is to complete the function linearProbing() which takes as input a empty hash table (hash), the hash table size (hashSize), an integers array arr[] and its size N and inserts all the elements of the array arr[] into the given hash table.

The empty cells of the hash table are to be given a value of -1. Also, if there's no more space to insert a new element, just drop that element.

Expected Time Complexity: O(N). 
Expected Auxiliary Space: O(1).

Constraints:

```
1 <= hashSize <= 100
1 <= sizeOfArray <= 100
0 <= Array[] <= 105
```

The code I wrote is:

```
static int[] linearProbing(int hash_size, int arr[], int N) {
    int[] a = new int[hash_size];
    for(int i = 0; i < hash_size; i++)
        a[i] = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int probe = arr[i] % hash_size;
        int offset = 1;
        while(a[probe] != -1) {
            probe = (probe + offset) % hash_size;
        }
        a[probe] = arr[i];
    }
    return a;
}
```

The given testcases are running. But when submitting I am getting TLE. Please help.

The driver code is given as follows =
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULVdd.png

Comment: Though this might not be the case. What will happen when the complete hash array is filled. In that case you won't have any empty position left and the while loop will never stop.

Comment: Oh I forgot about that. Can you suggest the required changes?

Comment: Link is not working. Page is an internal 404

Comment: Can you check whether this case will happen? Can you have hash_size < array size ?

Comment: What is what here? Without the problem, we can't evaluate your code. is `arr.size() == N` or why are you iterating over `i = 0 .. N` and accessing `arr[i]`?

Comment: I have added the question.The reason that I am iterating over i = 0 .. N is because in the question array is given and we have to add to the hash table and then return the hash table.

Comment: As mentioned, there will be a case when the hash table size will be lesser than the array size. Your algoirthm is on the spot but doesn't handle this condition and goes into a infinite loop. ` Also, if there's no more space to insert a new element, just drop that element.` < = You aren't doing this part

Comment: @papaya thnx I will try to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed out one single point, when the array size is bigger than the hash table, just skip the rest.

This could also be the simple point, Just replace N with hash_size and iterate. This would let you only iterate as long as `arr` contains elements

```
static int[] linearProbing(int hash_size, int arr[], int N) {
    //This is what was missing from your code
    int iterating_size = N>hash_size? hash_size : N;

    int[] a = new int[hash_size];
    for(int i = 0; i < hash_size; i++)
        a[i] = -1;
    int started = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < iterating_size ; i++) {
        int probe = arr[i] % hash_size;
        int offset = 1;
        while(a[probe] != -1) {
            probe = (probe + offset) % hash_size;
        }
        a[probe] = arr[i];
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Thnx @papaya I got it.